# Set shortcut number to IntelliJ's tool windows

Tags: intellij-idea

i wonder if it's possible to set a own shortcut to IntelliJ's tool windows. The default shortcut for the Project tool window is ALT + 1 and i would like to change this or assign a shortcut to per example the Persistence tool window which have no default shortcut.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set it in settings -> keymap (just search for window you need)

Comment: Nice! I was sure it's possible but it seems, I'm blind ;).

Comment: In case that's plugin window, it usually is under "other" section in settings -> keymap

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the tool window shortcut in keymap(IDEA 2017.2 For MacOS). See this picture:

[keymap for tool windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KciFA.jpg)